# Auto-create folders from excel file

Tags: c, file, directory

I want to create about 1000 folder, but I think the best way isn't "Create new folder - rename it".   I have a excel file  (.xls) with a column full with the preferable names..

eg

names.xls
column 1 = name1, name2, name3 , name4 ,name5 , name6   etc

column 2 = amount1 ,  amount2, amount 3, amount 4. etc

So I want a folder with a name test, and inside it  I want all the folders with the names of column 1.. Is it possible and how that think can be done? I think the best language for this job is C, or not?  Is excel file a problem? May I insert the 1st column from xls file to an txt file?

Comment: Not C. You can use Visual Basic (build-in to Excel depending on your version). Or, you can export the document as .csv file and use a scripting language such as python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to do this might be to this:

1. Insert a column before column 1 with the command to create a directory (md)
2. Fill it downwards for all the rows with values in the name column (now the 2nd column)
3. Copy the two columns to a textfile
4. Search and remove whitespaces if needed
5. Save the textfile as .bat or .cmd and execute it in the correct directory

If this is a one time thing writing a program could be overkill, but if you need to do it often go with VBS as suggested above.

Comment: with this solution I have wrong permisions:/  I tried it on linux and only root have enabled permissions on this folders. Can throught mkdir command  give me preferable permission?

Comment: Forget my question..   now I see on mkdir command the structure.. 

mkdir -m 777 example_dir   and I am ok!